# Динамическая форма

Tags: html, javascript, php

Прошу помочь нюбу. Искал информацию, но толком ничего не нашел.

Вопрос следующий. Мне нужно создать анкету (форму). К примеру, у меня первое поле, в котором я должен ввести значение. По мере ввода проверяется, правильно ли введены данные. К примеру, 6 вариантов. Если введен правильный вариант, то к каждому из 6 вариантов предлагается выбрать свой список допустимых вариантов как выплывающий список. Далее можно еще раз то же самое, допустим, к каждому из вариантов выплывающего списка еще список. Реализовано тут http://www.nvidia.ru/Download/index.aspx?lang=ru

Когда все поля заполнены, то выплывает подсказка с инструкциями, а внизу отправить на обработку в пхп, где пхп записывает данные в базу. (Обработка и запись - это не сложно, как реализовывается знаю, помогите с подстановкой вариантов в зависимости от предыдущего ответа.)

Буду очень благодарен за совет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напраление действий.
**Вариант первый:**
Создаем дерево всевозможных вариантов, типа:

```
$tree = new Array();
$tree['firstStringFirstInput'] = new Array();
$tree['firstStringFirstInput']['firstStringSecondInput'] = new Array();
$tree['secondStringFirstInput'] = new Array();
```

итп. После чего из этого массива достаем значения.

**Вариант второй(как у н-видиЫ):**
После каждого изменения инпута делаем ajax апрос, в котором передаем имя инпута и его значение. В зависимости от этого создаем SELECT запрос к базе данных с выгрузкой значений для следующего инпута формы.

Answer (score 0):

это Ajax // лучше ищи jQuery Ajax PHP validation